# On Andrica's conjecture.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

We have Andirca's conjecture as: $$\sqrt{p_{n+1}}-\sqrt{p_{n}}<1$$ I have no clue if this is a proof. I was just messing around. (And plus, my methods are probably too elementary).
Denote $g(n)$ as the difference between $p_{n+1}$ and $p_n$. i.e., $p_{n+1}=p_n+g(n)$. Playing and messing around a little bit gives us : $$p_{n+1}-2\sqrt{p_{n}p_{n+1}}<1$$ So we have to prove this. In other words, prove that:$$p_{n+1}<2\sqrt{p_{n+1} p_n}+1$$ So we make a claim:
Claim: $$p_{n+1}<\sqrt{2 p_{n+1} p_n }$$

**Proof:** This statement is equivalent to $$(p_{n+1})^2<2(p_{n+1})(p_n)$$ This is quite easy to prove. I am not good with latex. What I did was write $p_{n+1}=p_n+g(n)$. Then expanding both sides and cancelling out gives us: $$g(n)^2<(p_n)^2,$$ which is obvious.
Now using this claim and working backwards, we obtain the initial result.

I think I am wrong, but I just don't know where. It seems too elementary.

UPDATE: I have a new claim. Messing around some more, I obtained $$g(n)^2/(4p_n)<1$$ is equivalent to Andrica's conjecture.

UPDATE: I reduced this conjecture to $2S\sqrt{a}>g(n)$, where $S$ is the sum from $n\leq x$ of the $\frac{\mu(n)}{n}$, and $a=p_{n+1}-g(n)$. And since $S=1$, we have $2\sqrt a>g(n)$

Comment: I think I know where I when wrong. Instead of p_n in the beginning expansion, I wrote p_n+1.

Comment: since $p_{n+1}> p_n$, the claim $p_{n+1}<\sqrt{p_{n+1}p_n}$ will never hold.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter Yeah I know. That's why I proved the stronger p_(n+1)<2sqrt(p_(n+1)p_n)+1.                                                                                                                        Wait, I claimed p_n+1<sqrt(p_(n+1)p_n). Sorry I meant the above statement I just stated. (p_(n+1)<2sqrt(p_(n+1)p_n)+1).

Comment: Your statement $p_{n+1}-2\sqrt{p_{n}p_{n+1}}<1$ is incorrect; you left out a term. Simple squaring of the premise leads to $p_{n+1}-2\sqrt{p_{n}p_{n+1}}+p_n<1$.

Comment: Some of the results you stated are quite [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica%27s_conjecture).